# Are Suparnas an intelligent supernatural species?

Tags: supernatural

The Manusmriti lists some celestial or supernatural races as being related:

> **[3.196](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199981.html)** - The Barhisads, the sons of Atri, are declared to be the Pitṛs of Daityas, Dānavas, Yakṣas, Gandharvas, Uragas, Rākṣasas, **Suparṇas** and Kinnaras.

All these races are known to be intelligent, including the horse-headed kinnaras.

However, Medhatithi thinks that Suparnas are just animals:

> ‘Suparṇas’—are a particular kind of birds.
>
> ...
>
> The purport of this laudatory description is that—so essential is the performance of Śrāddhas that even Daityas, Dānavas and Rākṣasas, who generally interfere with sacrificial performances, cannot avoid it; **nor even animals, who have no intelligence and no memory.** [referring to the Suparnas]

There is also another mention of Suparnas in the Manusmriti:

> **[12.44](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202223.html)** - Cāraṇas, **Suparṇas**, hypocritical men, Rākṣasas, and Piśācas—represent the highest state among those partaking of the quality of ‘Tamas.’—(44)

Here Medhatithi also says they are a particular kind of birds:

> ‘Suparṇas’—a particular kind of birds.

However, I don't think Suparnas are just birds, because in verse 3.196 above, the Suparnas are mentioned alongside other intelligent species. If the Suparnas were just birds, what would be their significance in listing them alongside the other great intelligent races?

Also, there is a species of intelligent birds called the *Garudas*, of which Garuda and Aruna (charioteer of Surya) are members of. The Garudas feast on the Nagas in Patala.

So what scriptures describe the Suparnas?

Comment: I think i saw somewhere that Suparna means a bird  having golden wings. Sometimes the word also used for surya in vedas.

Comment: Suparna is another name of Garuda - https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01034.htm "And all creatures became exceedingly glad, beholding that excellent feather of Garuda so cast off. And seeing that the feather was very beautiful, they said, 'Let this bird be called Suparna (having fair feathers)'"..

Answer (score 2):

'su' means well and 'parna' means wings. So 'Suparna' means well-winged birds according to sanskrit dictionary : [http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=सुपर्ण&lang=sans&action=Search](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3&lang=sans&action=Search). **Good-winged Birds do have intelligence and are not necessarily super-normal species.**

> Well-winged,’ designates a large bird of prey, the ‘eagle’ or the ‘vulture,’ **in the Rigveda** and later. In the passages in which it appears as an eater of carrion it must be the vulture. **The Jaiminiya Brāhmaṇa** mentions an eagle which separates milk from water like the Kruftc. **In the Rigveda the Suparṇa is said to be the child of the śyena, and is** **distinguished from the latter in another passage**: this led Zimmer to think that the falcon is probably meant. The **Atharvaveda** alludes to its cry, and describes it as living in the hills.

suparṇa Is personified in the **Yajurveda Saηnhitās** as a Rṣi.

In Mudaka-Upanishad we get

> Dva suparna sayuja sakhaayaa samaanam vriksham parishaswajaate meaning two birds, always associated and of the same name are embracing the same tree (Ref:Stavakusumanjali, Swami Gambhirananda, Udbodhan, page 79)

'Suparna' is the 192th name mentioned in the Vishnu-Sahasranaama : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu_Sahasranama.

'Suparna' is also the name of Garuda. Garyda is of course Supernatural.

Comment: Ok but are they intelligent?

Comment: @ikshvaku i dont know how the IQ of birds is measured

Answer (score 1):

Rig Veda I.164.47 says

> kṛṣṇaṃ niyānaṃ harayaḥ **suparṇā** apo vasānā divamut patanti | ta
>   āvavṛtran sadanād ṛtasyādid ghṛtena pṛthivī vyudyate ||
>
> Dark the descent: the ***birds*** are ***golden-coloured***; up to the heaven they
>   fly robed in the waters. Again descend they from the seat of Order,
>   and all the earth is moistened with their fatness.

---

Agni is the carrier of food to devas.  In Rig Veda Agni was described as spreading from EARTH to HEAVEN.  So originally, AGNI was described as ascending to Heaven, as a bird with golden wings.

---

In the subsequent literature, this word Suparna was deified as Garuda, a mighty bird.

In Ramayana, Garuda was described as Suparna.

> ततः ***सुपर्णह्*** काकुत्स्थौ दृष्ट्वा प्रत्यभिनन्द्य च | विममर्श च
>   पाणिभ्याम् मुखे चन्द्र सम प्रभे || ६-५०-३८
>
> Thereupon, Garuda the eagle, coming into contact iwth Rama and
>   Lakshmana d offering them his good wishes, with his hands caressly
>   touched their faces that were radiant like the moon.